# How to declare generics for a method that returns a Function with generics

Tags: java, generics, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I'm trying to use some kind of pattern matching in java, so i came up with this method:

```java
public Function<SimpleEntry<T, R>[], R> matchWith(T match){
        return functions ->  Stream.of(functions)
                .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals(match))
                .findFirst()
                .map(Entry::getValue)
                .orElse(null);
    }
```

This obviously doesn't work, and i can't find a related question about that.

The idea is to use the method like this:

```java
final String value = matchWith(Type.B).apply(
        new SimpleEntry<>(Type.A, "Type A matches"),
        new SimpleEntry<>(Type.B, "Type B matches")
)
```

Note: I'll probably need to declare the return type like this `Function<Pair<T, R>..., R>` to have that.. which i don't know how to do too.

So how to declare generics for a method that returns a Function with generics?

Comment: Generics and arrays do not mix, because an array has a distinct type at runtime, but generic types are only known at compile time.  Use a List or Collection instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to supply your own functional interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Matcher<T, R> {
    R apply(Entry<T, R>...entries);
}
```

```
private static <T, R> Matcher<T, R> matchWith(T match) {
    return functions ->  Stream.of(functions)
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals(match))
            .findFirst()
            .map(Entry::getValue)
            .orElse(null);
}
```

```
final String value = EnclosingClass.<Type, String>matchWith(Type.B).apply(
        new SimpleEntry<>(Type.A, "Type A matches"), // could also use Map.entry in Java 9
        new SimpleEntry<>(Type.B, "Type B matches")
);
```

Also, it looks like type inference isn't smart enough to figure out that it should return a `Matcher<Type, String>`, so you have to manually supply the type arguments (like I did above, where `EnclosingClass` is the class that declares `matchWith`).

---

What arguably works better though is to pass the list of entries to `matchWith` directly, then you don't need the interface, and it is also able to work out the right return type automatically:

```
private static <T, R> R matchWith(T match, Entry<T, R>...enries) {
    return Stream.of(enries)
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals(match))
            .findFirst()
            .map(Entry::getValue)
            .orElse(null);
}
```

```
String value = matchWith(Type.B,
        new SimpleEntry<>(Type.A, "Type A matches"),
        new SimpleEntry<>(Type.B, "Type B matches")
);
```

---

As a fun fact, some similar functionality like you're trying to create might be added to `switch` statements in the future: [JEP draft: Switch Expressions for the Java Language](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8192963)

Comment: i saw this one here http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/amber/pattern-match.html which seems to be good too, i don't know if its a proposal or something but it's interesting

Comment: @GabrielDeOliveiraRohden Yes, here is the JEP: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/305 It's something they're looking at (but not making any promises). And here is a talk about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3_8YcYKScw

Comment: there's seems to be a bug for the eclipse java compiler (which i don't use, but some members of the team use) when using the last method you wrote, the compiler seems to lose the correct type inference, the bug is here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=508834

Comment: @GabrielDeOliveiraRohden Looks like it's fixed in the latest versions. I'm using eclipse myself and it works fine for me in both Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a) and Photon Milestone 4 (4.8.0M4). The bug itself is also marked 'verified fixed', so I'd advice your team members to update.

Answer (score 1):

Not only with functional programming, you can define generics to methods arguments and return types using Target Types.

```
public <T, R> Function<Pair<T, R>[], R> matchWith(T match) {}
```

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

Comment: oooh :o, thanks, now the 'initial' diamond 'makes sense' to me (i didn't knew that i should declare the  generics there)

Comment: @GabrielDeOliveiraRohden To nitpick on your comment, the "diamond operator" only refers to the type-infering version on the right hand side of an assignment - eg `new ArrayList<>()`.